Hybrid recommendation system
I am building a recommendation system on the Movie Lens dataset. I want to use the movie  descriptions to build content based filtering to suggest movies to new users and to solve the Cold start problem (using TF-IDF,  word2vec  embeddings etc.). Then use actual Neural Collaborative Filtering to suggest movie based on rating. I am using Pytorch.
How do I combine these models?.
What models to use for both?.
How would my architecture look like?.
It would be helpful if you guys could provide resources.
